# Setting language in a fakeApplication() for Play! 2.0.2

Tags: testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

```
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Content html = views.html.index.render(loginForm);
            assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
            assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("log in");
        }
    });
```

We use this code to test that a view is rendered properly, but the problem is that the text in the view doesn't use the Messages.en-file we have specified for our actual application (so it renderes login.login instead of "log in" for instance).

Is there a way to configure the fakeapplication to use a specific langauge (and then have it look for the appropriate messages-file)?

We tried this to no avail:

```
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
    config.put("application.langs", "en");
    FakeApplication fakeApp = new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put("application.langs", "en");
FakeApplication fakeApp = new FakeApplication(new java.io.File("conf/"), Helpers.class.getClassLoader(), config, , new ArrayList<String>())`;
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that I can't pass 'path' and 'additionalConfiguration' as they are not variables (i.e. the test won't compile. Also, the fakeApp-constructor wants a file for the path.

Comment: That made the test compile, but the Messages.en-file still wasn't read. Any way to see if the application uses a specific language in the HTTP request?

Comment: In your view, you can print the languages using `request().acceptLanguages()`

Comment: Ok, I think the problem is that I'm simply using 'views.html.<viewname>.render()', which apparently doesn't invoke the Controller, and as such apparently doesn't utilize the configuration files.